# What is the most affordable means of storing 3,000+ gallons (11,000+ litre) of rain water?

Tags: water, storage

I'd like to setup some rainwater storage, collecting water from the rainy season, so use later on the garden. The hardware stores sell water storage containers, but to store 3000 gallons (11,000 litre) would require $5000 of containers. In prehistoric times, people just built a pond-like reservoir nearby my house, but I believe the water would just evaporate. Is there a cheaper alternative for storing water? I have a 50 ft by 50 ft (15 metre by 15 metre) area of land to use.

Comment: Depending on where you are at, storing large amounts of rainwater can actually be illegal...

Comment: I checked my local laws. It is permitted in my state.

Comment: LA covered several of their reservoirs with black plastic balls to reduce algal growth and evaporation and to deter wildlife.. They've since replaced them, on most reservoirs, with floating covers for legal reasons, but perhaps the technique could work for your pond. Google: LA Shade Balls

Comment: It’s hard to get cheaper than to store water with the rest of the water underground.

Comment: I edited to add SI units, but can you confirm if that is imperial gallon, US gallon, or US dry gallon?

Comment: @CaiusJard Didnt they stop that practise because they worked out it was giving practically no benefit for the cost involved ?

Comment: One of the reservoirs still uses them? As far as I was aware the science pointed to significant cost savings in terms of the amount of chlorination required, and that they're a cheaper form of cover than other variations. I don't know of any authoritative reason why they are no longer deployed across all LA reservoirs, but I haven't read anything related to cost(3 reservoirs use more expensive floating covers) The question, ultimately is not whether it works for a 175 acre reservoir but whether it would help solve this smaller scale problem more cost effectively than a tank, of course

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

### Single large tanks

They sell plastic water tanks in the $1000 range for 3000 gallons (11000 litre).  Two such tanks were famously seen in *Breaking Bad* season 4, as the repository for both the magic “methylamine” they needed, and also for the (spoiler alert).

Figure on 8 foot (2.4 metre) diameter x 10 feet (3 metre) tall.
These tanks are absolutely enormous and come on a flat bed truck; the trucker will expect you to have a backhoe and rigging necessary to pick the tank off the back of the truck.

You could probably fetch one yourself, e.g. if you found a bargain on Craigslist; but to move it we’re talking a big 8 foot (2.4 metre) wide 2-3 axle trailer with a Reese hitch, and a big macho vehicle to pull it.  It’s not the weight, it’s the wind resistance - you don’t want your trailer or tow vehicle tossed out of control or flipped over entirely!

[image]

### Arrays of small tanks

Country folk have a single “go-to” container: the  “intermediate bulk container” or **IBC Tote**. These are pallet-sized (40 x 48”, 1 × 1.2 metre) and hold usually 275 or 330 gallons (1040 or 1250 litre; note: multiples of 55-gallon / 208 litre drums). They are 4-5 feet (1.2-1.5 metre) tall.

Now, you can buy these new *if you really, really, really want to*... and I’m sure factories get quite a good price on them by the trainload. But the people proffering them in single quantity *really stick it to ya* - they’d brazenly charge $4 for a 2-liter soda-style bottle. (You can get ‘em full of soda for $2).

On the other hand, they’re usually single-use containers, especially food-grade ones, so industry winds up with a whole lot of ‘em.   Now, some clever people on Craigslist will clean them out for you and sell them to you for $35 to $75, but your best bet is call around to industry and service providers, and see who has way too many of them and will let you have em for nothin’.

I recently had a need for one, and a friend immediately offered me one from his workplace’s overstock, and driving through the local sawmill I saw another 30 or 40 piled up.

Comment: Those large black tanks you show can be cheaply obtained as orange or any fruit juice transport containers - just have to look for them same as the totes you mention.

Comment: I edited to add SI units, but can you confirm if that is imperial gallon, US gallon, or US dry gallon?

Comment: They are OP gsllons.  Looking at OP apparently 3000 gal = 11,000 l, whatever that tells you.

Comment: Inspect tanks carefully upon delivery.  Our neighbor had 3 large tanks delivered. He signed for the delivery and the truck left before he fully inspected the tanks.  One had a crack from crumpling due to a too-small pallet, another had 2 nail holes, probably from hitting an adjacent pallet.  He then began months of finger-pointing limbo stuck between the manufacturer and the shipper and the credit card company trying to resolve who was to blame.

Answer (score 12):

In large parts of the world this is routinely done with underground concrete cisterns. Odds are that's the common way because it works effectively and for the long run, though I'm sure plastic tank suppliers would prefer you buy a plastic tank. Given that a 3000 gallon (11000 litre) plastic tank is still going to require major equipment to install, the benefit of the tank being lighter is quite limited.

What your local installed cost is and/or any use limitations (such as load limits on top of a plastic tank that may be much lower than on top of a concrete tank) would be one factor - the odds of a leak and/or length of guarantee on the tank not leaking might be another consideration.

I recall my precast concrete septic tank at around half this capacity as being remarkably affordable, delivered to the hole.

Comment: I edited to add SI units, but can you confirm if that is imperial gallon, US gallon, or US dry gallon?

Answer (score 9):

As people have mentioned, in other parts of the world, and on farms, rainwater is often collected in cisterns.   And they are not always dug in pits, or underground.  If you are collecting from a roof top, you can use containers along side the building, or in a separate silo like building.   I've seen silo like cisterns used by residences in the Caribbean islands.  This has the advantage of not having to pump the water up for use.

I just googled "rainwater cistern system" and found this commercial site which shows a variety of examples of plastic, fiberglass, and metal tanks including some with supporting or protective structures.
[Examples of cistern systems](https://www.watercache.com/portfolio/rainwater-cisterns-tanks)

Answer (score 9):

In France we can get soft water cisterns. I don’t know if they’re available in the US. They look like this:

[image]

[This one](https://www.la-citerne-verte.com/citerne-verte-10-m-etroite.html) holds 2600 US gallons (2200 imperial gallons, 10000 litres).

Comment: “Pillow tank” is a good search term. “Bladder tank” is also used but is less specific.

Comment: I edited to add SI units, but can you confirm if that is imperial gallon, US gallon, or US dry gallon?

Answer (score 5):

Ponds are a significant modification to a property. The water will percolate into surrounding soils, evaporate from the surface, and attract pests like mosquitoes to the stagnant water.

If you were going to try to establish one, a simple plastic liner isn't all it takes. Perhaps if you have clay and silty soils you could just keep filling it with water until it created a sufficient barrier but this will take time and land planning. If your have structures anywhere near this then forget about it.

I would see if you can find a deal on plastic septic tanks. Bury one, drop a pump into it, and reuse the water. None of the risks if the pond and no loss of land use.

Answer (score 3):

Dig out a 20'x20'x15" (6m × 6m × 4dm) deep area and line it with a single plastic liner. That will give you 500 cu ft (14.4 m³). 3000 US gallons = 401 cu ft = 11.4 m³. You would have enough room for an extra 748 US gallons (2830 litre).

Comment: Wait...   It's not good enough to be just a mosquito breeding ground but also a watering hole for animals after they get thirsty after eating all the vegetables in the garden...    It's an answer that meets all specifications but literally might be the worst thing to do for a gardener.   You never want to leave out water on the ground next to a garden.   This is farming 101 stuff.

Comment: Answer to mosquito larvae problem: mosquito bits/dunks. Answer to evaporation problem: make your pond as deep as possible to reduce surface area and cover it with plastic sheet or shade balls. Invest into some metal mesh to stop animals from drinking from the pond.

Answer (score 2):

In the American Southwest, where the law often forbids watering of any kind due to drought, some people have large plastic cisterns capturing rainfall from the roof. I don't know how much they cost but they work well and hold lots of water.  Someone mentioned them earlier and with a link. Aside from looking industrial and possibly clashing with your home decor, this is a good option. I'd say the ones I've seen are 6-8 feet (1.8–2.4 metre) in diameter and tall enough to fit beneath the gutters on the roof on either side.

Comment: @ChristianLescuyer but cheaper than your option - I picked up 8 for free and connected them in parallel, work fine for minimal cost...

Comment: Free is a good price!

Comment: Everything free has a cost too, mind!

Comment: If someone else mentioned them with a link, and you have no idea where to to get them or what they cost, then what value does this answer add?

Comment: @HenryA hey hey hey, calm down. Pipe was perfectly polite there. Your answer is just reiterating content already found on this page. It might be sensible for you to check out the [tour], to help you understand that this site is less conversational and more content focussed. Pipe is giving you advice in order to help you participate better: if being told the rules of the house you’re in scares you off, that’s a you problem, I’m afraid.